# django mongo db exception on syncdb command

Tags: django, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, django-mongodb-engine

I am using `django 1.5.5` with `django-mongodb-engine version 0.5.1.`

I installed djangotoolbox via following command:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
```

In python dist-packages, `djangotoolbox` version is `1.6.2`.

Getting this error on `syncdb command` call.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/madmin/workspace/milkyway/apiserver/startup.py", line 57, in startup
        load_initial_data=False)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 161, in call_command
        return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 255, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in handle
        return self.handle_noargs(**options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 109, in handle_noargs
        emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 195, in emit_post_sync_signal
        interactive=interactive, db=db)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 170, in send
        response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 88, in create_permissions
        "content_type", "codename"
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 139, in _result_iter
        self._fill_cache()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 941, in _fill_cache
        self._result_cache.append(next(self._iter))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1143, in iterator
        for row in self.query.get_compiler(self.db).results_iter():
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 375, in results_iter
        results = self.build_query(fields).fetch(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 482, in build_query
        query.order_by(self._get_ordering())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 543, in _get_ordering
        "non-relational backends (%s)." % order)
    DatabaseError: Ordering can't span tables on non-relational backends (content_type__app_label).
```

Comment: As mongodb is a non-rel db so there is no pre-defined column header so you don't have to do syncdb when you are using mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved.

Please see this link for complete uninstallation of Django.

[Uninstall Django completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897851/uninstall-django-completely/20897900?noredirect=1#comment31367901_20897900)

Uninstalling django properly is important in upgrading to new django version.

I did django installations again, using django-nonrel via following command:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
```