# ImportError: No module named 'dash' for Django 1.10.3

Tags: python, django

Strange, this happened after i upgraded to 1.10.3 on Ubuntu 16, Anaconda Distribution. The old 0.9 worked fine for me. Reinstalled multiple times as well, no difference.

```
➜  django-admin startproject django_tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'dash'
```

Can't find anything on google, anyone have any ideas? :)

EDIT:

Django-admin is installed at:

```
➜  ~ which django-admin
/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/bin/django-admin
```

Stuff I've tried so far:

1) Multiple `pip uninstall Django` and `pip install Django`

2) Verifying site-packages has Django uninstalled and reinstalling again

3) After uninstall, `pip freeze | grep Django` shows nothing.

4) `pip install django-dash`

Solves it, but now the error is `ImportError: No module named 'dash.development_settings'`

Strange:

```
python -m django --version
```

throws the same `ImportError: No module named 'dash.development_settings'` 
but I can run python in a terminal and do

```
import django
django.get_version()
```

and it works fine

Comment: Try working in a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), so you know if its a problem with your app or with your django installation

Comment: The command was for starting a new project, not an existing app

Comment: Doesn't matter. Create a virtual environment, and install a clean Django there, then try creating a project. If the problem persists, it isn't because of your upgrade. If it is the upgrade, then you can either work in the VE (which is better anyway) or manually remove all the Django library files and re-install

Comment: I had the same error. I think it happens  cause you didn't delete old version of django. try to remove it twice. then instal the version you need

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy How did you remove it? i tried pip uninstall twice and it shows no such package called django. installed again and it still doesnt work

Comment: Go to the `site-packages` folder (you an see the path in the error above) and delete the folder Django manually, not through pip.

Comment: try search django manually.  maybe you have different versions of django for different version of python http://stackoverflow.com/q/20897851/4592608

Comment: Also, looks like you're using Anaconda, that's probably relevant, so add that info to your post (because Anaconda uses isolated environments and you might be mixing something up there)

Comment: The site packages folder does not have django, but other stuff like pyinstaller has bits and pieces of django (i guess it comes with that library). The pip freeze | grep django method shows nothing too.

Comment: Please show `requirements.txt` file

Comment: Django is obviously installed incorrectly. That's the problem. Either use a virtual environment, or you need a clean install (which means you need to find where you django is installed, remove manually and re-install with pip)

Comment: @yuvi I did that already. Clearly the clean uninstall isn't working

Comment: Did you try working in a virtualenv?

Comment: Again, `pip uninstall` is not enough. You can try `pip install Django --upgrade -f` which will forcibly re install django, but assuming your basic installation was screwed, using a virtualenv is the best possible course of action I can recommend

Comment: @yuvi A virtualenv may solve the problem, but I want to know why its not working in a default installation. I've checked the site-packages directory after pip uninstall and verified theres nothing remaining of the Django package, and its still not working. What do you mean by "basic installation"? of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the hell was wrong.

my `bashrc` had `export DJANGO_SETTINGS = dash.development_settings` or something like that (deleted it already) and removing that line worked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `django-dash` installed

```
pip install django-dash
```

Or remove `dash` and `dash.` related apps from `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply! :) now it changes to ImportError: No module named 'dash.development_settings'. Was it always like this? I never had this difficulty starting a new project before. How would i remove from installed apps when i haven't initialized the app yet?

Comment: in addition: python -m django --version throws the same error, but importing django within python and using get_version() works

Comment: Are You sure You started new project? I don't think so. Please show Your **settings.py** file

Comment: If you see my original post, the command i used was: django-admin startproject django_tutorial

Comment: OK, but new django project **don't have** `dash` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Don't ask me man, as i said, in django 0.9 this never happened. I never had to install django-dash either. and what do you mean requirements.txt? Of what? This is a new project